# Changing the number of items in an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

In my Android app, I have a listview that initially displays a number of items. I then want to reload the listview with a new set of items. Typically, I do this to initially create the listview items:

```
adapterDirectories = new DirectoryAdapter(context, R.layout.shop_directory_row, directories);
lvDirectory.setAdapter(adapterDirectories);
```

My adapter looks like this:

```
  private class DirectoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShopDirectoryInfo>
  {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public DirectoryAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ArrayList items)
    {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
```

When I want to update the items I do this:

```
directories = getDirectories();

ArrayAdapter<ShopDirectoryInfo> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<ShopDirectoryInfo>) lvDirectory.getAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

What this ends up doing though is adding the new items to the existing ones, even though getDirectories returns a completely different set of data. I have no idea why the new items are prepended to the existing set instead of replacing the old set. The only way to get the new data to show up without the old data is to recreate the adapter instead of using notifyDataSetChanged. Is there a way to get the update without calling notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: are you sure you are clearing the list before setting the adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
adapterDirectories.notifyDataSetChanged();
lvDirectory.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the adapter again, you should clear the previous items like this.

```
if(adapter!= null) {
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: @AndroidDev after clearing, add the new items to adapter using `adapter.add()` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`...

Comment: did you call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); soon after you set the new data..

Comment: @AndroidDev in place of clearing adapter, you can also try to clearing the `arrayList` that you are passing to adapter, just before you are adding new values in it and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @PankajKumar please read comment again. I wrote `clearing the arrayList that you are passing to adapter *just before you are adding new values in it* and then call notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @PankajKumar Ahh, didn't see that one coming. As the answer was not correctly formatted, I didn't see, that nowhere in it, there is any way shown to update the adapter with new values. Thanks for pointing that out and I think that my other comment is just what is needed as addition to this answer.

Comment: @VishwasSharma Hey nop :) welcome. Now he does not need our answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
ArrayAdapter<ShopDirectoryInfo> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<ShopDirectoryInfo>) lvDirectory.getAdapter();
adapter.clear();

directories = getDirectories();
adapter.addAll(directories);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The key is to use addAll after clearing.

Comment: this works fine for Android 3.0 (API Level 11) and beyond, but not in previous versions